# If I am not logged on the machine, the script does not check if the mail has arrived Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, com-automation

Morning,
I have implemented a script that is run every day that needs to check if an email, with predetermined parameters, has arrived.

The script works and opens outlook only if I am logged in on the machine.

If I run the process without being logged in on the machine, the script does not interface with outlook (be clear does not give errors).

I attach the code.

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true")
messages = messages.Restrict("[Subject] = 'XXXX')
```

Can you provide support ?

Answer (score 1):

> If I run the process without being logged in on the machine, the script does not interface with outlook (be clear does not give errors).

Outlook may not recognize the profile to open without logging in.

Also Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply
I was thinking about one thing though. On another process, I send a report always from outlook. In this case, even if I don't log in, the script interfaces correctly with outlook and sends the report.

How come?

It seems that I can't automate the opening and reading of the inbox.